# HQL CASE statement usage

Tags: hql, case, conditional-statements

I'm using HQL and have this query

```
<query name="rule.myRule.query.by.name">
    <![CDATA[
        FROM rule.myRule as cr
        WHERE cr.name LIKE :name
        AND cr.type = 'myType'
        CASE 
            WHEN COUNT(cr.childRules) > 0
        THEN 
            cr.childRules LIKE :name
    ]]>
</query>
```

I need some help making this query correct. What I want is to have the condition cr.childeRule LIKE :name execute only when the count of cr.childRules >0 .

Where am I wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
FROM rule.myRule as cr
left join cr.childRules childRule
WHERE cr.name LIKE :name
AND cr.type = 'myType'
and childRule.id is null or childRule.name = :name
```

should do what you want.

Comment: Thx for the reply. The problem is this query will also return null childRules. I want to return the child rules only if they exist otherwise return nothing.

Comment: Then just remove the is null clause and use an inner join rather than a left join. But I don't understand what you were trying to achieve with your case statement then.

Comment: In my mind the case clause would have acted like this : if the rule has a child (i.e. count(cr.childRules) > 0) then add the cr.childRules LIKE :name clause to the query otherwise just retrieve the parent rule.

Comment: Then that's precisely what my query does: accept the parent rule if it doesn't have any child rule (i.e. childRule.id is null) or if it has a child rule with the given name. Note that a where clause is just used to accept/reject parent rules, not to fetch child rules.

Comment: Ok, thx for the help. 

Can you help me with the following topic : 
What about if the childRules could also have childRules ... and I would like to filter the childRules' childRules to the same pattern ?

Comment: You would need an additional left join. But you won't be able to apply such a restriction recursively.

Comment: Is there any method of applying this sort of a restriction recursively ?